# android webview could not open a link fired from bootstrap pop up

Tags: android

Could not detect any event fired from bootstrap popup

There a link for downloading the file on item click in bootstrap pop up, but android webview  is unable to detect the url or even the click event on it.

My Code :

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    mWebView.loadUrl(homePageUrl);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    //mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); // transparent
    /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }*/

    //mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            //CommonUtils.getInstance().showMsg(MainActivity.this,"Alert!",message);
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    //replace your java script method with this "CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()". 
    webView.evaluateJavascript("CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
      messagedata = value;
      Log.e("webview ", "" + messagedata);
     }
    });
    }
```